# html responsiveness working when re-sizing screen but not when using inspect element phone view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, resize

I am coding a website as part of a project. I have written code to make it responsive, using both media queries and bootstrap classes, and everything seems to work when I re-size my screen by dragging it from the corner. However, when I resize the page via the inspect element method, my screen just gets smaller and no responsiveness is shown.

This is my home screen after no re-sizing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDugW.jpg)

Home screen after re-sizing by dragging the screen across:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GQxX.jpg)

Home screen after inspect element resizing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmcON.jpg)

this is my code for my home page:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "C:\Users\Lenovo User\Documents\uwe_code\Webdev_coursework\styles.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--nav bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#HTNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">Horizon Travels</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="HTNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><img src="C:\Users\Lenovo User\Documents\uwe_code\Webdev_coursework\Images\logo.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <br><br><br><br>
        
        <!--travel options-->
        <div class="homeBox container-fluid">
          <br><br>
          <a href="planeBookings.html">View Plane Bookings</a>
        </div>
        <div class="homeBox container-fluid">
          <br><br>
          <a href="trainBookings.html">View Train Bookings</a>
        </div>
      <div class="homeBox container-fluid">
        <br><br>
        <a href="coachBookings.html">View Coach Bookings</a>
      </div>

      <div class="footer container-fluid" style="text-decoration:none; position:fixed;">
        <br>
        <p>© 2022 Horizon Travels. All rights reserved &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="privacystatement.html">Privacy Statement</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Horizon Travels</p>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

`

```
.register-form {
    border: 2px solid;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: grey;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.register-form-container {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 725px;
    width: 1000px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.95;
}

.login-form-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 375px;
  width:1000px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.95;

}

body {
    background-image: url('https://tahititourisme.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/ICThalasso_030718_0751_HD%C2%A9RomeoBalancourt-1920px.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    /* For mobiles: */
    .col-x-1 {width: 8.33%; font-size: 6px;}
    .col-x-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-x-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-x-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-x-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-x-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-x-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-x-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-x-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-x-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-x-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-x-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%; font-size: 13px;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%; font-size:20px;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

  .homeBox {
    border: solid 1px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  
  .footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
```

`

I tried using both media queries and bootstrap but still nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this inside your `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```